# How to do upsert with serializer in django rest framework mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, serialization

I'm trying to accomplish `upsert` functionality using `serializer` in `django-rest-framework-mongoengine`

Here's my code:

**Model**

```py
class SocialAccount(Document):
    uid = StringField(max_length=60, required=True)
    platform = StringField(max_length=20, required=True, choices=('facebook','twitter','youtube'))
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), required=True)

    meta = {
      'collection': 'social_accounts'
    }
```

**Serializer**

```py
class SocialAccountCreateSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SocialAccount
        fields = [
            'id',
            'uid',
            'platform'
        ]
```

**View**

```py
class SocialAccountCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = SocialAccount.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SocialAccountCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(app_id=self.request.auth)
```

Instead of saving the serializer, how can I do upsert using the serializer or use serializer data to perform upsert?

Thanks